# Need l10n for description of a Firefox add-on

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing a Mozilla Firefox add-on and I am trying to implement l10n in the extension. I need to provide l10n for description of the add-on which is available in the *package.json* file. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Interesting, im not sure about the package.json, but can you make it an xpi? And after making it an xpi can you edit the install.rdf? If you can then you can localize the install.rdf like this: https://github.com/Noitidart/l10n/blob/xhtml-xul/install.rdf  If this is not an addon-sdk addon, and regular bootstrap addon you can follow any of the guides in my l10n demo branch, its very easy to localize, I show how to localize HTML pages (has to be XHTML) XUL, jsm/bootstrap js files, and install.rdf. Heres my repo: https://github.com/Noitidart/l10n/

Comment: And heres an MDN entry: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions#Localization_%28L10n%29 and of course to get the community to help you localize put up your addon at babelzilla: beta.babelzilla.org/projects/ and then create a topic on the forum informing them you have done so as I did here: http://www.babelzilla.org/forum/index.php?showtopic=7665&hl=nativeshot